# 7000+ Records in CSV file for 100 Threads in JMeter Test Plan

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, sample

So I'm working on JMeter and I tried to run a test plan (with only one script: edureka.co that further has 6 scripts when viewed in Result Tree like https://www.edureka.co/-0 https://www.edureka.co/-1 till https://www.edureka.co/-5) with concurrency thread group with 100 threads, 200 sec Ramp-up time and 2 Ramp-up steps. I ran this test plan in Non-GUI Mode of JMeter and to my surprise I got 7880+ records in my CSV File. Max I should have gotten like 600 records.
Anyone can tell why I'm getting this much records in my CSV file and what does the scripts https://www.edureka.co/-0, https://www.edureka.co/-1, https://www.edureka.co/-2 till https://www.edureka.co/-5 mean. (they show up even with 1 thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For these `-0`, `-1`, etc. there is an explanation:

   - first couple is being caused by [redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) to `https://www.edureca.co`
   - next requests stand for images, scripts and styles - so called ["embedded resources"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)

   [image]

   this is **absolutely normal** as long as JMeter sends the same requests as the real browser does, the only piece of advice I can give is to add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your test plan as real browsers download these embedded resources only once.
2. `Max I should have gotten like 600 records` - this is not true, the number of "records" depends on the application response time and related metrics (connect time, latency, network bandwidth, etc). If you want to limit the number of results to 600 only either switch to normal [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with 100 threads and 6 loops or use [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) to limit the number of requests to 600 only

   [image]